# TortoiseHg: How to match a node hash to its revision node in the revision graph?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I gave someone a copy of my code using `hg archive` a while ago. A lot of commits has happened since then and I cannot remember which was the revision I gave him. There is some information about the version I had given the person in the `.hg_archival.txt` file. It has the node hash information, for example `node: 72f497079285b2c3cf4f8b86950664f84221cd63`

Using the information in the .hg_archival.txt file (like the node hash) how do I find the corresponding revision node in the revision graph displayed in TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works with TortoiseHg 2.x.y. If the **Filter Toolbar** is not visible, enable it by choosing `View -> Filter Toolbar` or pressing `Ctrl+S`.

In the **revision set query** textbox of the Filter toolbar paste the node hash and press Enter. If the **Filter check box** is set, only the revision matching the hash is displayed. If you disable the **Filter check box**, the revision matching the hash is highlighted in the complete revision graph.

The complete hash is 40 characters long. You only need to paste enough of it to be able to unambiguously match a revision.

Comment: It looks like in the current version the way that you specify that it is a Revision Set is to put the changeset id into parentheses.  Tripped me up until I discovered that.

Answer (score 3):

`hg log -r 72f497079285b2c3cf4f8b86950664f84221cd63` or `hg  update -r 72f497079285b2c3cf4f8b86950664f84221cd63`

Comment: Note you only have to type enough of the hash to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Mark: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not know it accepted hashes of any small length as long as it was unambiguous.